# Многопоточное выполнение кода

Tags: многопоточность, оптимизация, производительность, распараллеливание

Сейчас изучаю многопоточное выполнение и постоянно натыкаюсь на статьи и посты типа "Параллельно значит быстрее", но насколько это правда?
Если с асинхронностью всё понятно, она позволяет не "усыплять" тред на I\O операциях, то на параллельном выполнении немного запутался.
Правильно ли понимаю, что параллельное выполнение ЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНО повысит скорость только если нагрузка на процессор маленькая и у него есть возможность выполнять созданные потоки на нескольких ядрах? Т.е. если попытаться запустить параллельную обработку при 100% CPU bound будет либо незначительный прирост в производительности, либо вообще просадка в из-за свапа контекста + создании и удалении нового потока.
З.Ы.
Я только учусь, не критикуйте сильно =С

Comment: да, в некоторых случаях это может быть медленнее чем в один поток.

Comment: При параллельном выполнении ваша задача утилизировать все доступные ядра процессора. Было 100% CPU на одном ядре, стало 100% CPU на восьми ядрах.  В идеале в восемь раз быстрее.

Comment: Тут больше вопрос при 8 ядрах и 100% CPU bound и создании новых тредов)

Comment: Если все процессоры уже заняты, параллельность не может ничего дать - вы и так едете на максимальной скорости.

Comment: Да именно поэтому и возник вопрос, если утрированно: ребята с фрейморков говорят о том, что чем больше потоков - тем быстрее выполняется обработка распаралленной операции, а ребята с кс говорят, что без разницы сколько вы потоков запустите количество ядер уже всё решило за вас) upd: Без учета гипертрединга офк)

Answer (score -2):

Параллельное выполнение дает преимущества только в cpu-bound задачах при условиях что на хосте больше одного ядра.

До популяризации асинхронности процессы использовались для независимой обработки коннектов. Иногда fork на каждый accept, иногда по треду на каждый accept. Такая обработка позволяла принимать несколько сотен коннектов. Потом программы усложнились и чтоб не тратить время на создание нового потока стали переиспользовать потоки которые уже отработали. Но остался оверхед на копирование данных чтоб сделать доступ к ним потокобезопасным.

Есть некоторые io задачи на которых нельзя поставить асинхронность. Например чтение из чего-то медленного и не буферизованного. Потоки тут ускорят обработку.

Например эффективно сделано в библиотеке libuv. Там сочетается многопоточность и асинхронность. На каждую ио операцию определяется колбэк. Потоки по очереди выбирают указатели на колбэки из петли и выполняют их. Большую CPU операцию можно прерывать на проверку ио операций просто заменив цикл на рекурсию.